# Reducing the size of edittext in android

Tags: android

I'm very new to android and I want to reduce the size of `EditText` field in my layout.

For example if the user only need to enter 3 digits to the text field, then the size of the `EditText` should be small enough not the one provided by default.

Is that possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="20dp" //size your choice
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Layout file set the attribute to that text field width as

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`..This will take  `width` as the text `content entered into the field`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
**android:layout_margin="size you want"**

use can also use 
**android:layout_margin_left="size you want"**

instead of "**left**" you can also **right**, **top**, **bottom**.